# Create ROC curve with for loop or sapply

Tags: r, loops, roc, proc-r-package

After a lot of searching I could not find an answer to my problem. I would like to generate a ROC curve with the pROC pakkage using a for loop or sapply.

My database looks like this (only with 26 colums and 74 rows):

```
PT Bpt PA mnT1G mnT01
1   1  1   2.3   4.5
1   2  0   1.2   3.2 
2   1  1   5.4   2.1
```

I can make a ROC curve 'manually':

```
plot.new()
roc1 <- roc(cor.datT$PA, cor.datT$mT1G, percent=TRUE, partial.auc=c(100, 90), partial.auc.correct=TRUE, 
            partial.auc.focus="sens", ci=TRUE, boot.n=100, ci.alpha=0.9, stratified=FALSE, plot=TRUE, col= 'red')
roc2 <- roc(cor.datT$PA, cor.datT$mT01, plot=TRUE, add=TRUE, percent=roc1$percent, col = 'blue')
```

For 'automatic' I tried:

First roc curve always mnT1G:

```
rocT1G <- roc(cor.datT$PA, cor.datT$mnT1G, percent=TRUE, partial.auc=c(100, 90), partial.auc.correct=TRUE, partial.auc.focus="sens", ci=TRUE, boot.n=100, ci.alpha=0.9, stratified=FALSE, plot=TRUE, col= 'red')
```

Add other roc curves (data$Img are all the image names (like T1G, T01, etc) from another dataframe). I understand they all will be blue :

```
sapply(unique(data$Img[data$Img != "T1G"]), FUN = function(i) paste("roc",i,sep="") <- roc(cor.datT$PA, cor.datT[paste("mn",i, sep = "")], plot=TRUE, add=TRUE, percent=rocT1G$percent, col = 'blue'), simplify = FALSE)
```

But I get this error:

> Error in roc.default(cor.datT$PA, cor.datT[paste("mn", i, sep = "")], 
>   :    Predictor must be numeric or ordered.

Same happens with for loop:

```
for (i in unique(data$Img[data$Img != "T1G"])){
    plot.new()
    rocT1G <- roc(cor.datT$PA, cor.datT$mnT1G, percent=TRUE, partial.auc=c(100, 90), partial.auc.correct=TRUE, partial.auc.focus="sens", ci=TRUE, boot.n=100, ci.alpha=0.9, stratified=FALSE, plot=TRUE, col= 'red')
    paste("roc",i,sep="") <- roc(cor.datT$PA, cor.datT[paste("mn",i, sep = "")], plot=TRUE, add=TRUE, percent=rocT1G$percent, col = 'blue')
}
```

I checked the columns and they are all numerical. So maybe something goes wrong with the class in my script?

Comment: edit your question to have code displayed properly. You can find specific options at the top of the edit box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted in a comment on my other answer, the problem is that you get specifically `data.frame`s out of your extraction.

In a `data.frame`, extracting with a single character returns a `data.frame`. This is documented in [?Extract.data.frame](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html):

> Data frames can be indexed in several modes. When [ and [[ are used
>   with a single vector index (x[i] or x[[i]]), they index the data frame
>   as if it were a list.

And looking at [?Extract](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html):

> Recursive (list-like) objects
>
> Indexing by [ is similar to atomic vectors and selects a list of the
>   specified element(s).

This is not so obvious from the text, but in order to extract a column into a vector, you need to use two brackets `[[`, so

```
class(cor.datT[[paste("mn",i, sep = "")]])
```

should be a vector.

Now the following code should run:

```
rocT1G <- roc(cor.datT$PA, cor.datT$mnT1G, percent=TRUE, partial.auc=c(100, 90), partial.auc.correct=TRUE, partial.auc.focus="sens", ci=TRUE, boot.n=100, ci.alpha=0.9, stratified=FALSE, plot=TRUE, col= 'red')
for (i in unique(data$Img[data$Img != "T1G"])){
    roc(cor.datT$PA, cor.datT[[paste("mn",i, sep = "")]], plot=TRUE, add=TRUE, percent=rocT1G$percent, col = 'blue')
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works!! However next problem, in line with last one, is generating the roc objects. When doing this manually the class of object rocT1G, rocT01 is "roc". In the loop the class is "character". How do I get the loop to generate the right class?

Comment: This is the error:                                                                                        Error in paste("roc", i, sep = "") <- roc(cor.datT$PA, cor.datT[[paste("mn",  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object

Comment: Yep you can't assign a ROC curve to a string. But do you need to assign it at all? Let me try to edit my answer

Comment: This should run, but of course without a reproducible example in your question it is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

One of your column is not numeric as you expect. Unfortunately the error message from R doesn't tell you at which iteration of the loop the problem occurs, but you can easily add `print` statement to your loop to figure out which column yields the problem

```
for (i in unique(data$Img[data$Img != "T1G"])){
    print(i)
    plot.new()
    rocT1G <- roc(cor.datT$PA, cor.datT$mnT1G, percent=TRUE, partial.auc=c(100, 90), partial.auc.correct=TRUE, partial.auc.focus="sens", ci=TRUE, boot.n=100, ci.alpha=0.9, stratified=FALSE, plot=TRUE, col= 'red')
    paste("roc",i,sep="") <- roc(cor.datT$PA, cor.datT[paste("mn",i, sep = "")], plot=TRUE, add=TRUE, percent=rocT1G$percent, col = 'blue')
}
```

The last column number printed will be the one. You can see what is going on with the column:

```
class(cor.datT[paste("mn",i, sep = "")])
str(cor.datT[paste("mn",i, sep = "")])
```

More generally you can inspect all the columns of your data frame quite quickly with

```
str(cor.datT)
```

Check out for columns of class `character` or `factor` in particular.

Comment: Thank you Calimo. The classes of the columns in dataframe cor.datT are all numerical. With print(class(cor.datT[paste("mn",i, sep = "")])) it shows that the loop makes them all dataframes. How can I get them to stay numerical in the loop?

Comment: Good catch, let me post a new answer